# (Process String) in Java program

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I want to help me in this program.
Write a program that prompts the user to enter a string and displays the characters at even positions.

```
package lab6b;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner("Enter a number:");
        char s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.charAt(i); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                continue;
            } else if (i % 2 == 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Java and JavaScript are entirely separate languages. 2) What is your question?  3) Note that SO is not a place to seek general help, you need a specific question which has a specific answer. 4) This has nothing to do with Java EE or Swing either.  Choose your tags more carefully in future.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Scanner: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html. Hint: you want to read from System.in, not from the string "Enter a number:"

Comment: This is a total hotchpotch of strings, int and chars all in one go. Please elaborate your concern.

Comment: Ok. . But what is the solution to the question because I did not understand well ??

Comment: I was able to understand none out of the question and the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string:");
String enteredString = in.next();
for (int i = 1; i < enteredString.length(); i+=2) {
    System.out.println(enteredString.charAt(i));
}
```

But I think you have to look into things like Scanner, String, loops etc...

Answer (score -1):

The use Scanner class for input you must pass `System.in`as argument,then use`<object>.nextLine()`to accept String object then iterate from 1 to `s.length()-1` with increment by 2.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a sentence"); 
   String s=in.nextLine();
   for(int i=1;i<s.length();i+=2)
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
   //I assume the user understands the string begins with 1...s.length()
}
```

Comment: *//I assume the user understands the string begins with 1...s.length()*: I hope he doesn't understand that, because that's incorrect. Your answer should explain what the OP got wrong, instead of providing code that he can copy and paste, but that he won't understand.

Comment: But does not enter text when I run the program. . What is the problem?

Comment: @BaraZorob: the coputer talks to you, the user, when it says "Enter a sentence". So **you** are supposed to enter a sentence.

Comment: Your words are true, but this does not do not know where the problem ??

Comment: Thus my prints     run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @BaraZorob You need to understand the difference between compiling code, and running it. You have only compiled it, i.e. transformed .java source files into .class files. Then you need to run your program. Go see your teacher, or re-read your course manual, because you're missing a lot of basic stuff.